# when is the call stack really empty?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, callstack

https://promisesaplus.com/#point-34

> onFulfilled or onRejected must not be called until the execution
> context stack contains **only platform code**.

Promises (`then()`, `catch()`, `finally()`) and `async` functions are executed until the *call stack is empty*.

Therefore, does this basically mean that the main JavaScript thread **has to finish all its code first** to execute the promises and `async` functions? only then will the call stack be empty, right?

Does "platform code" mean that the JS thread finished its code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Therefore, does this basically mean that the main JavaScript thread has to finish all its code first to execute the promises and async functions? only then will the call stack be empty, right?

Yes, whatever event callback initiated the current execution thread has returned control back to the event system.  That's when the promise system can then call the completion callbacks for this promise.

> Does "platform code" mean that the JS thread finished its code?

"Finished" is a bit of an ambiguous word here.  "Platform code" means that the user's code has returned control back to the event system and the event system can decide what to execute next.  The user's code may not have actually "finished" doing what it's doing because it may still have asynchronous callbacks that are waiting to execute.  But, it did return control.

Here's an example:

```js
console.log("start");
Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    console.log("promise finished");
});
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("timer processed");
}, 50);
console.log("end");
```

This generates the output:

```
start
end
promise finished
timer processed
```

The promise (which is immediately resolved) does not call its `.then()` callback until after `console.log("end");` is executed and this code returns control back to the event system.

And, note that the timer is still in process so the code before was not completely "finished", though it did return control back to the event system.

Comment: hi,@jfriend00 +1, "return control back to the event system"  - means that our code (**the synchronous code**) in the *main JS thread* is finished, and that only the pending asynchronous callbacks are left, right?

Comment: @Coder23 - Yes.  Since nearly every piece of Javascript you execute (except the very start of your program) is in response to an event callback (it's an event-driven system), it means that your event handler has returned and now the system's code will decide what to execute next.  Some people call this "returning control back to the event loop", but promises technically execute before what most people think of as the event loop in something like nodejs so I just say "returns control back to the system".

Comment: excellent @jfriend00 +1 this worth gold, one last question just to confirm, the `async` functions are also executed until the *call stack* is empty, right?

Comment: @Coder23 - I'm not sure what you mean about `async` functions.  Perhaps you should write a new question and show an example.  An `async` function returns a promise and that promise behaves as we've described here, but `async` functions can also be suspended with `await` and then they immediately return a promise in the "pending" state.

Comment: `async` function, I mean the functions that use `await`  (`async-await`) inside their body @jfriend00

Comment: @Coder23 - Details of how `async` and `await` work are beyond what we can cover in comments here.  If you have a specific question about that, please write a new question.

Answer (score 1):

it would be like this console.log("first");

let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { setTimeout(() => { resolve("second"); }, 3000); });

promise.then(value => { console.log(value); console.log("third"); });

console.log("fourth");

//first //fourth //second //third //
Yes, the main JS thread has to finish all of its code first before executing promises and async functions. In this example, when the main JS thread finished executing the console.log("fourth") statement, the callstack was empty and the promise can begin to be executed. The value "second" is logged after "fourth" because it took the promise 3 seconds to resolve, before the callstack was empty. "Platform code" refers to any code that isn't user defined, such as code written by the browser or deployed library.

Comment: hi @Rashid Khalil +1, thanks for confirming this

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, the call stack is used to execute synchronous code. Asynchronous code, such as code that involves callbacks or promises, is executed outside of the call stack in the event loop.